# How to handle CNAME host redirect to virtual directory?

Tags: redirects, url-rewriting, iis7, cname, localhost

I have an internal website and virtual directory `http://server2012/logs`. I created a CNAME on my DNS server as LOGS -> server2012. I would like to set it up so that `http://LOGS` redirects to `http://server2012/logs`. Ideally, I would still want it so that all pages appear in the browser as being off from the LOGS URL. So `http://LOGS/network.html?site=32` is what is displayed in the browser, but it is really being served from `http://server2012/logs/network.html?site=32`. I've looked at URL rewrite, but can't seem to get to work.

Comment: You visit the site, yet no comment to my answer?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is at all possible. The LOGS need to be its own virtual server.

So essentially, set up a new virtual web server (if you're using Apache this is a breeze,) with it's root folder pointing to the same folder as this one does: in `http://server2012/logs/`.

Then, set up your DNS (bind?) to aim the internal traffic from `http://LOGS/` to the physical server.

To tie it all up, simply make the new virtual web server respond to only `http://LOGS/`, and the `http://server2012` web server, only respond to that.

I run this type of set up at my home office for developing client sites, and it's been running 20 or more sites at once for years without headaches.

Bare in mind, the /logs/ folder will still be accessible through `http://server2012/logs/`. If this is unwanted, you can probably fix that with the .htaccess file.

Edit: If it weren't clear already, this is obviously not a CNAME fix - you might as well us an A record. :)

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this easily enough in IIS 7.x:

1. Create the DNS alias/CNAME pointing `logs` to `server2012` --> You've already done this.
2. Create a new site on the server2012 that responds to the [host header](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) `logs` (or, better yet, the FQDN like `logs.domain.tld`)
3. Now you have two options:

   a. Use IIS 7's [basic redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732930%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) feature to direct the URLS to `http://server2012/logs/...` --> This will change the URL the user sees, not mask it like you were hoping.

   b. Use the more advanced [URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module) to mask the redirect/rewrite so it still looks like you're browsing `http://logs/...`

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Create a Condition: {HTTP_HOST} / Matches the Pattern / LOGS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="LOGS Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="LOGS" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="LOGS" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```